# AppEngine pricing and IO wait

Tags: google-app-engine, amazon-ec2, hosting, cloud-hosting

AppEngine pricing looks similar to Amazon EC2 pricing for single core instance

```
AppEngine  - $0.08 / hour
Amazon EC2 - Small (Default)    $0.080 per Hour
```

But it seems that I have to pay for time when my script is waiting for IO. I expected to pay for actual CPU cycles, not for waiting. When my script is waiting for DataStore or URL fetch then other scripts may execute on same core. In my test case 97-99% of time is script waiting for IO. So do I have to pay for 70-100 times more then I expected or would pay if I run on EC2 or a dedicated server?

I thought AppEngine is good for apps that scale but if I will have a high traffic then it would be a Kill Bill. Low hosting costs and a scalable platform are important. Are my estimations of AppEngine pricing comparing to Amazon EC2 correct?

Comment: Your app is still using memory during the time it's waiting - which is at least as significant a resource as CPU. EC2 is priced the same way - you pay for instance hours, not for CPU time.

Comment: With amazon ec2 small is 1.7 GB memory. 1-8 concurrent threads could be handled with much less memory. In fact my current app if written in Go and installed on RackSpace $12 per month instance.

Comment: App Engine is a Platform As A Service, while EC2 and Rackspace are Infrastructure As A Service, so the prices aren't directly comparable. If you think managing the infrastructure yourself - servers, backups, replication, load balancing, failover, and so forth - is a better deal, you are of course welcome to use any of those instead of App Engine.

Comment: @NickJohnson I do understand that AppEngine is different. But pricing per hour was exactly similar and misleaded me. If PAAS from google costs 10-100 times more then SAAS from someone then it make sense to invest a bit in SAAS rather using PAAS or avoid using datastore. Solution from Rekby lower costs but they are still high.

Comment: I don't know where you're getting your estimates, since the two aren't directly comparable. But as I say, if you really think your time is worth little enough that it's more cost effective to manage everything yourself, you're more than welcome to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn on multithreadind for java or python 2.7 applications. In multithreading mode every instance can work with 8-10 requests at same time.

Python:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests

Java:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Using_Concurrent_Requests

Comment: 8-10 requests limit. What is bottleneck? memory? Is there thread limit? Can I run my own thread not linked directly with any request? e.g. to poll stock price and update static variable?

Comment: 8-10 request per each instance. It is appengine limit, I think about process limit. It count independence of Instance type (I try with F1 and F4). I can't say anything about own processes - I don't need it. You can try - it is fast and simple.